# Conventional Approaches for Passing Data to Back-End?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm fairly new to web development, so please pardon the painfully newbie question that's about to follow.

My computer science class group and I are developing a web application for class, which is built in Python (under Django) and uses jQuery on the front end. It's primarily an Ajax-ified application, and passing data from the backend to the front end is done through Ajax calls to specific URLs which return in the JSON format.

This is probably a stupid question, but what's the conventional approach for passing data in the opposite direction? We don't want to reload the page or anything, so is it an Ajax pass going the other way or something?

Answer (score 3):

You simply send AJAX request and pack all the data to POST request params then read it in Django.

Example of basic voting app in django + ajax: http://lethain.com/entry/2007/dec/11/two-faced-django-part-5-jquery-ajax/